# WPF ~ Trouble with Binding & INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

WPF n00bie here, trying to get his UI to work properly.

So I made this test example. The textblock bound to HeaderText1 changes correctly at the launch of the app, but the textblock bound to HeaderText2 doesn't update after clicking the button.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.DataContextSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataContextSample" Height="142.596" Width="310">
    <StackPanel Margin="15">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Window title:  " />
            <TextBox Name="txtWindowTitle" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Width="150" />
            <Button Name="btnUpdateSource" Click="btnUpdateSource_Click" Margin="5,0" Padding="5,0">*</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.HeaderText}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.HeaderText2}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Main window class:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;


namespace DataBinding
{
    public partial class DataContextSample : Window
    {
        public string HeaderText { set; get; }



        public DataContextSample()
        {
            HeaderText = "YES";


            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;

        }

        private void btnUpdateSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            BindingExpression binding = txtWindowTitle.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            binding.UpdateSource();

            Source source = new Source();
            source.HeaderText2 = "YES2";
        }
    }
}
```

And the INotifyPropertyChanged class

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DataBinding
{
    public class Source : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string HeaderText2 { set; get; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are doing many things wrong.

You should not be using the window as it's own datacontext, you should have a viewmodel that you set.

You should not be using event handlers in the view to manipulate the viewmodel. You should bind the button to a command.

Your source seems to be a "viewmodel", consider renaming it to MainWindowViewModel (for clarity) and then do this.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string headerText;
    private string headerText2;
    private ICommand updateHeaderText2;

    public string HeaderText
    {
        set
        {
            return this.headerText;
        }
        get 
        {
            this.headerText = value;

            // Actually raise the event when property changes
            this.OnPropertyChanged("HeaderText"); 
        }
    }

    public string HeaderText2
    {
        set
        {
            return this.headerText2;
        }
        get 
        {
            this.headerText2 = value;

            // Actually raise the event when property changes
            this.OnPropertyChanged("HeaderText2");
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateHeaderText2
    {
        get 
        {
            // Google some implementation for ICommand and add the MyCommand class to your solution.
            return new MyCommand (() => this.HeaderText2 = "YES2");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And set this viewmodel to the datacontext of your window.

```
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

And then in your xaml you should bind to the viewmodel as such

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.DataContextSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataContextSample" Height="142.596" Width="310">
    <StackPanel Margin="15">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Window title:  " />
            <!-- Not sure what this binding is? -->
            <TextBox Name="txtWindowTitle" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Width="150" />
            <Button Name="btnUpdateSource" Command="{Binding UpdateHeaderText2}" Margin="5,0" Padding="5,0">*</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText2}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As a followup question, if I were to have a Model for the underlying logic, how would I handle the button's command? Send it from the view to the viewmodel, and then to the model? What would that look like in this example?

Comment: That is included in the sample, the implementation of the command is not, that should be easily accessed with google.

Answer (score 1):

You set the `DataContext` to `this` (the window). You don't have a property named `HeaderText2` in the `DataContext` so the second binding won't work.

I'd do this (without changing your code too much, in reality I'd do a proper MVVM approach):

```
public partial class DataContextSample : Window
{
    public Source Source { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { set; get; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        HeaderText = "YES";
        Source = new Source { HeaderText2 = "YES" };
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnUpdateSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindingExpression binding = txtWindowTitle.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (binding != null)
        {
            binding.UpdateSource();
        }

        Source.HeaderText2 = "YES2";
    }
}
```

I added a new property called `Source` which is of type `Source`. Set its initial `HeaderText2` to the same `"YES"` in the constructor and in the button click change that to `"YES2"`.

You have to change your `Source` class as well, to actually notify about changes:

```
public class Source : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _headerText2;

    public string HeaderText2
    {
        get { return _headerText2; }
        set
        {
            _headerText2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HeaderText2");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your XAML:

```
<StackPanel Margin="15">
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Window title:  " />
        <TextBox Name="txtWindowTitle" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Width="150" />
        <Button Name="btnUpdateSource" Click="btnUpdateSource_Click" Margin="5,0" Padding="5,0">*</Button>
    </WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HeaderText}"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Source.HeaderText2}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, and your edits make a lot of sense!

Comment: But regarding the proper MVVM approach; So i got the MainWindow class, which is  the view, and the Source class, which is the ViewModel. The model class should be the logic behind it all, correct? So when I click the button, the thread originates in the view's btnUpdateSource_Click, it should then send everything through source to a 3rd class, which then handles everything, and changes properties in the ViewModel, if needed, correct? Where would I move the DataContext then? Could you perhaps give a small example of a good MVVM approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a few issues with your code.
First of all, you never assign your "Source" to a datacontext, so there's no way for your second TextBlock to find the value of "HeaderText2".

If however you would assign your "Source" to the textblocks datacontext then we could fetch the value of "HeaderText2". Consider the code below

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.DataContextSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="DataContextSample" Height="142.596" Width="310">
    <StackPanel Margin="15">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Window title:  " />
            <TextBox Name="txtWindowTitle" Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" Width="150" />
            <Button Name="btnUpdateSource" Click="btnUpdateSource_Click" Margin="5,0" Padding="5,0">*</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HeaderText}"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlock2" Text="{Binding Path=HeaderText2}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

We have given your second Textblock a name, "TextBlock2" and also removed the "Datacontext"-part from your binding.

Then we have moved the Creation of your "Source" object from the button event to the windows constructor (there is no need to make a new one everytime we click a button when all we want to do is to update a property)

```
public partial class DataContextSample : Window
{
    public string HeaderText { set; get; }
    private Source source { get; set; }

    public DataContextSample()
    {
        ...

        source = new Source();
        TextBlock2.DataContext = source;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And then in your buttons click-event we assign your databound property a value of "YES2".

```
private void btnUpdateSource_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...

    source.HeaderText2 = "YES2";
}
```

There is however one more detail. Your class "Source" does implement "INotifyPropertyChanged", but it never "uses" it. By that I mean, that when you assign a value to your property "HeaderText2" you never actually "notify" the UI that something has changed with it, and thus the UI will not fetch the new value. Consider the code below:

```
public class Source : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public string HeaderText2 { set
        {
            headerText2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("HeaderText2");
        }
        get
        {
            return headerText2;
        }
    }
    string headerText2;

    ...
}
```

So let's take a look at what we've done with the property "HeaderText2". Everytime the "HeaderText2" gets a value assigned, it will first save the value in a privat property (so that we can read from it later). But in addition to that we also call the "OnPropertyChanged" method with our Propertys name. That method will in turn check if anyone is "listening" to our "PropertyChanged"-event (and since we have a databinding on the current object, someone is listening), and create a new event.

Now we have assigned a datasource to your textblock with a path to "HeaderText2", we are notifying all listeners when we update "HeaderText2" on the datasource and we are updating "HeaderText2" on the buttons click event.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. If I were to do this example in a true MVVM form, I'd need a 3rd class, correct? And then do all the logic in there, right? What would that look like?